# Custom animation interpolation without graph editor?

Tags: animation, interpolation

I did a bit of 2d animation and now I am working on 3d animations. In the past one was able to interpolate custom curves in 2d animation. As far as I know this is now gone, or at least I wasn't able to see it anywhere. For my animations I obviously want to interpolate different curves, however using the graph editor wasn't a very pleasant experience so far and actually somehow broke my animations (if I insert new keyframes after the keyframes where I used the graph editor it won't do anything).

The thing is, that I don't really need that much control for my animations. Being able to set custom curves (like in the 2d animations) for each interpolation would be more then enough.

Is there a way to set custom interpolations without using the graph editor? (I would also prefer coding my way around the graph editor if that is possible)

Comment: Not a criticism of your question.. but I am curious about the problems you're having with the Graph Editor, which at first sight, seems the obvious route. Maybe you could get help with those, here, as well.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more what you mean with "(if I insert new keyframes after the keyframes where I used the graph editor it won't do anything)" or ask a new question about it? I am pretty sure we could help you with that...

Comment: @Chris I have posted another question explaining the problem I have with the keyframe in more detail [Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239435/pose-of-keyframe-locked-after-using-graph-editor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Dope Sheet you can select one or more keyframes, right click on it and select the interpolation of the segments following the selected keyframes.

You can choose between ease in, ease out, ease in and out, and then choose between various interpolation rates (linear, sinusoidal, quadratic, cubic, ....., bounce, overshoot, elastic).

In 2D grease pencil also you can interpolate between two drawings choosing between rates presets or even a custom curve: in edit mode set the cursor between the two drawings and choose from the menu Grease pencil > Interpolate sequence (<kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>E</kbd>), then press <kbd>F9</kbd> to set or edit the curve and parameters.

I also suggest to maintain open a graph editor window, to follow the changes, and start using it directly, as it is very versatile and well implemented, if you had troubles probably you did some mistakes.

[image]

Comment: I realized that my question is a bit misleading. Though I take from this answer that it is not possible to interpolate a custom curve like it is in the 2D grease pencil in 3D animations without using the graph editor. Say if you want to start an animation fast and end it slow, there is no built-in function for that and one would need to use the Bezier interpolation and the graph editor to achieve that manually.

Comment: Graph editor is the way to go.